# gradle get subporject name, version

Tags: gradle

root project build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes Name: project.archivesBaseName,
                    Version: project.version
        }
    }
}
```

subproject A build.gradle

```
archivesBaseName = 'AAA'
version = '1.0.1'
```

subproject B build.gradle

```
archivesBaseName = 'BBB'
version = '1.0.2'
```

What i want is after run `gradlew build` on root project, in project A and B's manifest file, there's `Name: AAA Version: 1.0.1` and `Name BBB version: 1.0.2`.
But what i got is the Name is the project's name: `A`, and the Version is `unspecified`...

`Name: A Version: unspecified`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your `subproject` configuration closure in the `projectsEvaluated` callback closure:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    subprojects { subproject ->

        jar {
            manifest {
                attributes Name: subproject.archivesBaseName,
                        Version: subproject.version
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**why?**  because when your `subproject` configuration closure was executed in the root parent project (during configuration phase), values for `archiveBaseName` and `version` properties from subprojects were not yet evaluated so the `jar` configuration for Manifest attribute is not correct. You need to set this configuration when all projects have been evaluated ==> use `projectsEvaluated` lifecycle hook for that.